# Factors in unique factorization of multivariate polynomials

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Every degree $d$ polynomial $P$ in $\mathbb C[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ has a factorization into a product of irreducible polynomials $P=S_1\cdots S_l$ (unique up to scalar multiplication). I have a confusion about the factors $S_1,\cdots,S_l$.

Take for example the polynomial $$P=x^5 + x^4 y - 2 x^3 y^2 - 2 x^2 y^3 + x y^4 + y^5
$$
It factors as $P=(x-y)^2(x+y)^3$.

If I write $P=P_1P_2$ where $P_1=(x-y)^2$ and $P_2=(x+y)^3$ then we see that $P_1=(x-y)^2=(x-y)(x-y)$ so $P_1$ is reducible and similarly for $P_2$.

Or may be we should write $P=Q_1Q_2Q_3Q_4Q_5$ where $Q_1=Q_2=x-y$ and $Q_3=Q_4=Q_5=x+y$ and now the factors $Q_i$ are all irreducible.

To summarize, in our example the factors $S_1,S_2,..., S_l$ alluded to in the factorization result are $Q_1,...,Q_5$ and not $P_1, P_2$. Is my understanding of the statement correct? Thanks for your helpp!

Comment: By definition $\left ( x-y \right )^{2}$ is an irreducible polynomial. Hence $P$ has unique factorization $P_{1} \cdot P_{2}$. Does this answer your question or have I missed a bit?

Comment: Isn't $(x-y)^2=(x-y)(x-y)$ so it is not irreducible because it is the product of two non constant polynomials. Do I have a confusion about that?

Comment: Well, but that's not really a factorization but more simply a different way of writing a power. In terms of factorization, we consider those two things the same one.
It is normally considered a factorization any $ P = P_1 P_2 $ where $P_1 ≠ P_2$

Comment: What about the polynomial $x^2-2xy+y^2$ is it irreducible?

Comment: Clearly not. In fact, it is the square of a binomial, i.e. $x^2 -2xy + y^2 = (x-y)^2 $
I'd say that you can call it a polynomial factorization any time you turn a sum into a product.

Prima factorization may be a good comparison.

Comment: The same polynomial $x^2-2xy+y^2=(x-y)^2$ you call it irreducible and reducible at the same time. I think that's not ok!

Comment: If $\mathbb{F}$ is a field, a non-constant polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}$ if its coefficients belong to $\mathbb{F}$ and it cannot be factored into the product of two non-constant polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}$.

We are talking about polynomials, not products. So $x^2-2xy+y^2$ is reducible as it is a polynomial that you can write as a PRODUCT of non-constant polynomials. However, $(x-y)^2$ is irreducible since $(x-y)$ cannot be factored. The power is irrelevant as you're focusing on the polynomial (which is a SUM by definition). Hope this clarifies :)